# on deleting child record, the UI is still showing DOM components associated with removed record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model called "question" that has many "answer" object/model. I am able to add a new answer to a question but upon deletion the UI is not getting updated, although when I checked through ember plugin in chrome, the record is getting removed from the store.

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/emUwAJan/1/

there you can click on the "add" button on the table head, this will add a new record but when you try to delete it, the answer does not get removed form the UI. What do I need to do to  get rid of the deleted record from the UI?

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got to remove the answer from the collection of anwswers:

```
        actions:{
            delete:function(){
                var record = this.get('model');
                this.get('parentController.answers').removeObject(record);
            }
        }
```

[bin](http://jsbin.com/emUwAJan/6/edit)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. The only thing I would add to the answer is record.deleteRecord() since we need to remove the association as well as the record itself. Thanks again.